# Exception with JPA Query Spring

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I want to get List of my objects by jpa query
I'm using this code:

```
@Query("select vz from VzClass vz" +
            "join vz.PHClass phc on vz.ph = phc.id" +
            "join phc.GFClass gf on phc.id = gf.phouse" +
            "join gf.PIClass pi on gf.pic = pi.id" +
            "where vz.fi is not null and vz.ci is null and pi.prId in (:pIds)")
    List<VzClass> getVzByPIids(@Param("pIds") List<String> plIds, Pageable pageable);
```

But I get the exception:

```
unexpected token: vz"
```

What is the problem there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some missing spaces at the end of string literals. For example after concat the result is like "...from VzClass **vzjoin** vz.PHClass...". It should look like

```
@Query("select vz from VzClass vz " +
            "join vz.PHClass phc on vz.ph = phc.id " +
            "join phc.GFClass gf on phc.id = gf.phouse " +
            "join gf.PIClass pi on gf.pic = pi.id " +
            "where vz.fi is not null and vz.ci is null and pi.prId in (:pIds) ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape with an end of line or space like so:

```
@Query("select vz from VzClass vz\n" +
        "join vz.PHClass phc on vz.ph = phc.id\n" +
        "join phc.GFClass gf on phc.id = gf.phouse\n" +
        "join gf.PIClass pi on gf.pic = pi.id\n" +
        "where vz.fi is not null and vz.ci is null and pi.prId in (:pIds)")
List<VzClass> getVzByPIids(@Param("pIds") List<String> plIds, Pageable pageable);
```